# Applying random background color to RecyclerView but not getting the same color twice in a row

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to apply a random background color from a list of colors to RecyclerView list items,
however, I am trying not to get the same color twice in a row
I tried recursion with something like

```
fun setBackground(){
val newColor = getRandomColor()
if(newColor == lastColor){
setBackground()
}
/*..*\
}
```

where `setBackground()` is called in `onBindViewHolder()` and `getRandomColor()` returns a random color in an array from resources

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir sometimes `getRandomColor()` gets the previous color. I want the new color to be different from the previous one

Comment: Bon Echo, the problem is in the latter part of your code, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the function after recursion call, or just place the rest of the code in else statement:

```
fun setBackground(){
val newColor = getRandomColor()
if(newColor == lastColor){
setBackground()
return;    //RETURN THE FUNCTION HERE
}
```

Alternative:

```
fun setBackground(){
val newColor = getRandomColor()
if(newColor == lastColor){
setBackground()
}else{
...
}
```

When your function comes back to the previous function, it sets the value again which overrides the color set earlier in stack.

Also, you can do this easily without recursion if the above code is confusing you:

```
val newColor;
do{  
newColor = getRandomColor()
}while(newColor == lastColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're only setting the background if the newColor equals the lastColor. This is going to cause the background to always be the same color. You want do do

```
if(newColor != lastColor){
setBackground()
}
```

Comment: Hi @andrew 
```
if(newColor == lastColor){
setBackground() // here I am calling the same function to get another color instead of the last one 
}
```
I used here recursion where `if(newColor == lastColor) ` is part of `setBackground() `

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is causing the issue because when recursion returns, the outer layer of the function call is setting the background colour again.

I suggest you rewrite using a simple `do while` loop, following your logic:

```
fun setBackground(){
  do {
    val newColor = getRandomColor()
    setBackground()
  } while(newColor == lastColor);
}
```

You can further improve above code by pulling both the `newColor` variable and the expensive `setBackground()` method call, out of the loop.